# отменить действе ввод в input, когда открыто модальное окно

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Есть input. При наборе вне инпута, инпут фокусируется и продолжается ввод. Добавлен события "document.addEventListener(keypress", ()=>ref.current.focus()).
Нужно отменить ввод в input когда например открыто модальное окно. То есть когда открыта модалка, продолжается ввод.

Comment: Отпишитесь от слушателя при открытии модалки. Считаю это будет полезным для вас https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660131/how-to-removeeventlistener-that-is-addeventlistener-with-anonymous-function

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input')
const modal = document.createElement('div')
modal.textContent = 'Надо вызвать .blur()'
Object.entries({
  fontSize: '36px',
  color: '#fff',
  backgroundColor: '#4caf50',
}).forEach(([s, v]) => modal.style[s] = v)

void async function() {
  let i = 10
  while (i--) {
    await new Promise((s) => setTimeout(s, 500))
    document.body.appendChild(modal)
    input.blur()
    input.value = 'blur()'
    await new Promise((s) => setTimeout(s, 500))
    document.body.removeChild(modal)
    input.focus()
    input.value = 'focus()'
  }
}()
```

```html
<input type="text">
<br><br>
```